# ¿Cómo generar IDs con formato en Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

Quisiera saber como puedo generar una clave **autoincrementable** por ejemplo tengo este formulario.

[image: Datos Empresa]

No. Empresa tiene el formato de `000001` y necesito que cuando se registre otra empresa aumentar el formato a `000002`.

No se qué usar JavaScript o Django.

Comment: Hola, ¿a qué te refieres con el rango de 10?

Comment: tienes razón eso esta de mas gracias por la observación, lo quitare eso no es importante editare la pregunta

Comment: Quiero enteneder a qué te refieres cuando dices "al iniciar otra cotización", imagino que te refieres a crear una nueva, en ese caso el ID de la cotización todavía no existe en la base de datos, ¿qué pasa  si dos personas quieren crear la cotización siguiente a 000001, para ambos se les mostraría el 000002 y cuando intentes grabar alguna de ellas generará error

Comment: si es lo que trataba de explicar, y la verdad no se ni como darle el formato 000001, 000002 etc...  ni como evitar lo que comentas

Comment: Pero lo que muestras en pantalla son datos de la empresa y es ahi en donde veo el correlativo que indicas, ¿cómo cuadra todo esto en la cotización? Tal vez deberías ampliar un poco la explicación en tu pregunta incluyendo ejemplos de lo que quieres lograr

Comment: discúlpame si es cierto es que ando algo enrredado pero la lógica es la misma .

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38452/discussion-between-cesar-and-wootsbot).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como te comentaba por nuestra charla en el chat, no te compliques tratando de mostrar el ID antes de que exista, eso normalmente es propenso a errores.

Lo que recomiendo simplemente es que formatees el ID de la Empresa en alguna vista tipo "Detalle de la Empresa", para eso podemos crear una función que formatee el ID para que contenga 6 dígitos.

Haremos uso del método [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill) de las cadenas de texto:

```
>>> id = 1
>>> str(id).zfill(6) 
'000001'
>>> id = 22
>>> str(id).zfill(6)
'000022'
>>> id = 333
>>> str(id).zfill(6)
'000333'
```

Entonces, en tu modelo Empresa podemos crear un método para formatear su ID:

```
class Empresa(models.Model):
    # Tus campos

    def get_id_formateado(self):
        return str(self.pk).zfill(6)
```

Y en tu template correspondiente a la vista "Detalle de la Empresa" lo muestras:

```
ID de la Empresa: {{ empresa.get_id_formateado }}
```

Ahora, si al usuario se le ocurre hacer la búsqueda de la Empresa usando, por ejemplo, `000123`, lo pasas como parámetro ya que Django ya se encarga de hacer las conversiones necesarias para buscar el registro en la base de datos.

Las siguientes operaciones son todas equivalentes:

```
>>> Empresa.objects.get(pk='000123')
>>> Empresa.objects.get(pk='0000000000000000000123')
>>> Empresa.objects.get(pk=123)
```